# Google Play Books not downloading

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, download, ebook

I'm viewing free books on Google Play Books from my Windows 10 Laptop and Chrome browser but some books are not downloading. The three vertical line menu doesn't have the download option for some of them.

[image]

> **How can I download the book on my PC?**